# How to only show only news from UK using news search api

Tags: python, azure, bing, bing-news-search-api

Currently, my code is displaying news from south Africa and also America.
How does one only produce results strictly from the UK?

```
search_term = "flood, fire, storm"
date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
search_url = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/news/search"

headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" : subscription_key}
params  = {
"q": search_term,
"cc": "en-GB", 
"mkt": "en-GB","textDecorations": True, 
"setLang": "en-gb", 
"textFormat": "HTML", "sortBy": date
}

response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
response.raise_for_status()
search_results = json.dumps(response.json())

print(search_results)
```

Comment: What news service are you using?  ie whats the search_url?

Comment: Which MS graph API you are using ?

Comment: vicky kumar: I am using the bing news search API: https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/news/search

Comment: The search url is "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/news/search"

Comment: Thanks for the update , this is not a graph api , correct person will take a look at this question